# Simple Joomla and JQuery function not working

Tags: jquery, joomla

0
votar contra
favorita

I've searched everywhere but I couldn't find a step-by-step on how to use JQuery on Joomla 3.8. I'm creating a module and I'd like to use JQuery. So here what I have done:

1. downloaded jquery-3.3.1.js and put in /modules/mod_mymodule/js
2. Reading Joomla documentation, I added these lines on my /modules/mod_mymodule/mod_mymodule.php file:

   ```
   JHtml::script(JURI::base() . 'js/jquery-3.3.1.js');
   Jhtml::_('jquery.framework');
   Jhtml::_('jquery.ui');
   ```
3. At the bottom of my default.php file I added this:

   ```
   <?php
   $document = JFactory::getDocument();
   $document->addScriptDeclaration('
       window.event("domready", function() {
           alert("An inline JavaScript Declaration");
       });
   ');
   ?>
   ```

It was supposed to show an alert window when the page is loaded but it does not work. So what can I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong mootools method replace *window.event* to **window.addEvent**

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    window.addEvent("domready", function() {
        alert("An inline JavaScript Declaration");
    });
');
```

Comment: Any projects queries contact me